# Infinispan cache.put does not work

Tags: infinispan

I have created a two node cluster running Infinispan cache in replication mode. I see the cache comes up fine. and both the nodes connect to each other. I am here using TreeCache Api to convert the Map based structure to tree based as below:

```
private static Cache<Object, Object> Cache1;
private static TreeCache<Object, Object> Cache;

Cache1 = new DefaultCacheManager("infinispan.xml").getCache();
Cache = new TreeCacheFactory().createTreeCache(Cache1);
```

If i call Cache.put , I dont get any error but the entry does not get saved to the cache. I confirmed it by getting the data again which returns NULL.

```
Cache.put(fqn,key, value);

if(Cache.get(fqn, key) == null)
{
    System.out.println("Entry is not saved");
}
```

Below is the config file,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <infinispan xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="urn:infinispan:config:5.3 http://www.infinispan.org/schemas/infinispan-config-5.3.xsd"
      xmlns="urn:infinispan:config:5.3">

   <global>
        <globalJmxStatistics enabled = "true" allowDuplicateDomains = "true"/>
        <transport clusterName = "test_cluster">
           <properties>
              <property name="configurationFile" value="tcp.xml" />
           </properties>
        </transport>
   </global>

   <default>
     <clustering mode="replication">
        <async asyncMarshalling="true" useReplQueue="true" replQueueInterval="10" replQueueMaxElements="100" />
        <stateTransfer timeout="2000000"/>
     </clustering>
    <invocationBatching enabled = "true"/>
    <locking isolationLevel          = "REPEATABLE_READ"
             writeSkewCheck          = "false"
              concurrencyLevel        = "1000"/>
     <jmxStatistics enabled="true"/>
   </default>
</infinispan>
```

Is it that I am missing to initialize any thing?

Comment: Instead of Cache.put , I used the NodeAPI and it seemed to work. Do I understand Cache.put(fqn,key,value) does not work when using TreeCacheAPI?

Comment: See [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Tree+API+Module) examples on how to retrieve data.

Comment: I referred to that.. Since it said the doc is deprecated. I did not try to follow it.. So we can refer to this documentation it seems

Comment: Ok. I found another document link .. Will use that one. So the problem was the put api was going through as I saw the contents in the jrmc. But get API was used incorrectly.